# Element next to display:block?

Tags: html, css

How do I display an element next to another element that I have added **display: block** onto?

I have added display block to make it appear on a new line.

**HTML**

```
 <nav><ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav" id="help1"><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav" id="acom"><a href="news.asp">Accommodation</a></li>
      <li class="nav"><a href="contact.asp">Crieff</a></li>
      <li class="nav" id="clear"><a href="about.asp">Holiday Activities</a></li>
        <li class="nav" id="help"><a href="about.asp">Attractions</a></li>
                    <li class="nav" id="acomm"><a href="about.asp">Prices</a></li>
                    <li class="nav"><a href="about.asp">Location</a></li>
                    <li class="nav" style="border-right: none; padding-right: 0; margin-right: 0;"><a href="about.asp">Enquiries / Availabili</a></li>
    </ul></nav>
```

**CSS**

```
 #help {

        color: red;
       width: 90px;
       display: block;
       clear: both;

    }

#acomm {
        display: inline-block;

    }
```

I have attatched a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3krea9r4/

Comment: About what element you say?

Comment: Hi @AshotKhanamiryan I'd like prices to appear next to attractions

Comment: it's not clear what you want exactly

Comment: @AshotKhanamiryan currently prices is on the line below attractions. I'd like prices to be on the same line as attractions.

Comment: Can you use `float:left` in `li.nav` instead of `display:inline-block` ?

Comment: No, it appears to jump up to the top of the list :(

Comment: no, I said you use display:inline-block . Can you use float:left or it's important to use inline-block? like this http://jsfiddle.net/khanamiryan/3krea9r4/1/

Comment: In the markup it's `id="help1"` but in the css it's `#help{...}`.